# Sumover in QuickSight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to use the **Sumover** table calc in **QuickSight** (link that this is possible: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/sumOver-function.html) in order to show a sum total for the week while still displaying the data at the daily grain.

However when I tried to use this function in a new calculated field I got the following error:

> "We encountered an error trying to save your calculated field. Please
>   try creating it again."

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. But it was transient. I went back to the home screen, start a new analysis with the same data set and create the calculated field following the same procedure and it worked.

Comment: yes, this error seems to be transient for me as well... it happens sometimes in some session and other times it does not seem to work at all, very frustrating.  I can sometimes get things to work if I log off and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

The error, "We encountered an error trying to save your calculated field. Please try creating it again.", is one I normally get when making a change to a calculated field at the analysis-level instead of the data-level in QuickSight.

Check that all variable names are consistent between data-level calculated fields and analysis-level calculated fields.

Check that you're not mixing aggregated and non-aggregated fields as well, noting that data-level calculated fields **in my experience** do not contain aggregated sub-calculations.